# Verifying my proof: "the equation $2x - 6y = 3$ has no integer solution to $x$ and $y$"

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, diophantine-equations

Question:

> Prove the equation $2x - 6y = 3$ has no integer solution to $x$ and $y$.

I need to verify my proof I think I did it correctly, but am not fully sure since I don't have solutions in my book. I basically proved by contradiction and assumed there was an integer solution for x or y. I then solved for $x $ and $y$ in $2x - 6y = 3$ getting $x = 3y + 3/2$ and $y = x/3 - 1/2$ .since both $x,y$ are not integers I said it contradicts that $x$ or $y$ had an integer solution, meaning the original statement was correct. Did I prove this right, or should I redo?

Comment: You're on the right track, but *why* is $x = 3y + 3/2$ not an integer? Also, your statement that "both $x, y$ are not integers" is not correct: $(3/2, 0)$ is a solution with $y$ integral.

Comment: @T.Bongers I think since adding 3/2 will make it a rational number

Comment: Some tips for friendly math formatting: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference.

Comment: ggg.2(x-3y)=3; x-3y integer.Means: Left hand side is even.Hence?

Answer (score 2):

Rewind to the point where you say $x=3y+3/2$. We rearrange this to $x-3y=3/2$, then note that since we have taken $x$ and $y$ to be integers, $x-3y$ is also an integer. But $3/2$ is not an integer, a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you may write $$2x - 6y = 2(x-3y).$$  Since $x$ and $y$ are integers, so must be $x-3y$.  So $2(x-3y)$ must be an even integer, clearly being divisible by $2$.  But $3$ is odd.

Answer (score 0):

Your proof, as it stands, is not correct. Some particular issues:

- You get to a point where $x = 3y + 3/2$ and $y = x/3 - 1/2$ and state that "since both $x,y$ are not integers..."; this assumes the conclusion that you're aiming for.
- It's not true that both $x$ and $y$ are not integers. You could have one of the two be an integer, and the other not be an integer. For example, $(0, -1/2)$ and $(3/2, 0)$ are both solutions with $x$ or $y$ integral, but not both.
- Its not convincing that $3y + 3/2$ is not an integer (and the point immediately above shows that that claim is not true!).
- Stylistically, your assumptions are not explicitly stated and there is no introduction to the proof. You haven't stated that you're assuming $(x, y)$ to be a pair of integers solving a particular equation. Therefore, it's not clear how the contradiction is reached; at a minimum, you need to form the negation of the statement and clearly include assumptions.

So unfortunately, this is not a properly written proof. But it can be fixed without too much work; here's an outline to follow:

1) Introduce the players. Say "We proceed by contradiction. Assume that $x, y$ are integers such that $2x - 6y = 3.$

2) Isolate one of the variables and get the contradiction. Perhaps "Then $x = 3y + \frac 3 2$. Since $3y$ is an integer (why?), the sum $3y + \frac 3 2$ is not an integer."

3) Tell the reader why this is a problem. "This contradicts the assumption that $x$ is an integer."

Comment: yea I know, my actual written proof was much more detailed and better formatted. Im just lazy and quickly wrote a summary haha. But, thanks for pointing out the issues, they are really helpful

Comment: @ggg If you're asking a sincere [tag:proof-verification] question, then it's important to include the actual proof that you want to verify... rather than a "lazy [...] summary." Please don't waste people's time by doing that.

Comment: Exactly what made you thinking that this question is not a homework?

Comment: @peterh If you have a problem with my comments on meta, then discuss it there or flag them. Please do not harass me on main with irrelevant nonsense.

Comment: @T.Bongers I did not harass you, I am just surprised that you seem answering a no-context PSQ. What if the question would be deleted, would it make you happier?

Comment: You and I clearly aren't on the same page about context, then, @peterh. The asker included a reasonable explanation of what they had done and why, and how they had approached the problem. This is absolutely not a PSQ, and it's deeply disingenuous to call it that. Leave the meta on meta where it belongs. I'm not going to engage with you further here on main.